# How to place elements in the grey area of a material-ui dialog

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a fullscreen modal in my app with the modal's controls in the page top corner.

If I use the 'fullScreen' prop on the Dialog component, the modal takes all the place (no overlay grey area around the modal) and every component I place inside the Dialog is placed in the content of the modal.

```
<Dialog fullScreen open={isOpen}>
    <ModalControls />
    <MyView>
</Dialog>
```

How can I achieve a result similar to this:
[image]

Comment: You can work with percentage.
For example instead of having a <div> covering 100% of the screen in width and height you can set height to 70% and width to 90% so you will still have some space

Comment: can you also show us some HTML code you wrote

Comment: @Synapsis Sorry I forgot to mention that in the question but if I tweak the dimensions of the div inside Dialog, everything is white  around it. I can achieve the grey area around with the devtools by setting background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) on the element around my div (the element with classes MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation24 MuiDialog-paper MuiDialog-paperScrollPaper MuiDialog-paperWidthSm MuiDialog-paperFullScreen MuiPaper-rounded) but I can't find how to set it in my app code

Comment: Instead of using the devtools you could just add a div with transparency with display:none.
When you need the modal to pop-up you're going to make it appear changing its style to display:block

The modal can be added inside of that main div.
Most of the modals are made this way, and the one in your picture is too.